# need to keep \n as it is in DB

Tags: mysql, database, newline, special-characters

Hi I need to keep `\n` as it is in DB. I dont want it to get translated to new line. but it is getting translated. how can I resolve this?

```
    $this->addSql('insert into `translations` values(\'en\',\'{    ,       
        "signature_name1_lab":"<div>First name</div>\n",
        "signature_name1":"First name",
        "signature_name2_lab":"<div>Name</div>\n"
       
 }\')');
```

I tried keeping `\\n` but it got translated to new line. when I put `'\'n` then it is giving error. what wrong I am doing? in standalonhe query `\\n` working properly. but this query is inside `single quote`.

Comment: Try `'\\\n'` - 1st slash quotes 2nd one and 3rd one quotes literal `n` in PHP.

Comment: thank you..actually error is coming. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR), expecting ',' o
#24 0.793   r ')'

Comment: yes Akina..it worked without single quote and 3 \\\ as you suggested. I misunderstood. thank you so much Akina.